# Create a Backup of Azure SQL database to my machine using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, azure-sql-database

I am trying to create a backup of Azure SQL database on my machine using vb.net application.
What I have tried:

```
    If System.IO.Directory.Exists("c:\") = False Then System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory("c:\")
    sql.Connect("myserver.database.windows.net", "username", "password")

    With bk
        .Database = "dbname"
        .Files = "c:\" & "\MyAzure" & Today.Date.ToString("d-M-yyyy") & ".bak"
        .SQLBackup(Sql)
    End With
    sql.DisConnect()
```

But I got this error:

> [SQL-DMO]SQL Server myserver.database.windows.net must be upgraded to version 7.0 or later to be administered by this version of SQL-DMO.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Azure SQL Database does not support creating .bak files on-demand. Azure SQL DB [automatically backups up all databases](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-business-continuity/) using native backups to enable you to Point-in-Time restore your database to any point in time within the databases retention period. If you would like to create a BACPAC file on-demand, you can use the [Import/Export service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-export/).